# CSS Width of Page With a Margin

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [margin left and right on with 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394484/margin-left-and-right-on-with-100)

I have a textbox that I want to fill the width of the page but I need it to have a sizeable margin-left to give the appearance of being indented.  So if I have a style such as this:

```
.notesText {
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

I end up with the page extending another 20px out to the right to accommodate my textbox instead of the textbox just filling the existing width of the page. As page widths with vary by device, how do I format this to have a 20px left margin and then fill the remaining space of the page?

Comment: try `margin-left: 5%; width: 95%;`

Comment: @Andy that works and is super simple. Submit as answer and I will accept.

Comment: use a wrapper with 100% width and a contentholder with no width specified and 20px margin-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `margin-left: 5%; width: 95%;`

This will give you a variable margin which may or may not be what you want

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no `box-sizing: margin-box` I think what you'll have to do is set the margin on an outer wrapper of the `textarea`:

```
<label class="message">
    Message<br>
    <textarea ...></textarea>
</label>

label.message {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

    label.message textarea {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }
```